# Google app engine, imported jar running very slowly

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jar

I have exported code from a eclipse project to a jar file. When I access this jar file in a another standard java project it takes under 5 minutes to complete. On a servlet on Google App Engine, it is taking nearly an hour to complete. Is this just a feature of using Google App Engine, or is it possible there are other issues? I am using the servlet with a cron job to update the datastore, but the time taken to write to the datastore is only a small fraction of the total running time.

Update

The code is tagging a large amount of news articles for company names and there relevance to the article, using a Naive Bayes Classifier. This is what accounts for the length of time the program requires, but not why it needs so much more on the App Engine.

Comment: You need to profile it to see what's happening. Even 5 minutes is a very long time for a Java code to execute - it must be waiting on something or running a lot of loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to optimize a program without seeing it, but here are a few pointers.

The code on App Engine executes as fast as anywhere if not constrained. You should look into data access time (how fast you read your articles), data write time, and/or memory limitations. Apps like the one you describe tend to require a lot of memory.

1. You can check memory stats on App Engine console. If you bump into the limits, you can either use larger instances, or split your processing load into smaller chunks.
2. If you split your load into individual tasks and use a task queue, you can take advantage of multiple threads running on a single instance. This is usually a huge performance boost when reading/writing data is involved.
3. Make sure you use the right chunk size when reading/writing data. For example, queries in the Datastore have a default chunk size of 10, while you can increase it up to 1,000. The same logic applies to Datastore puts. It makes for a big difference in performance when you read/write thousands of entities. This applies to other storage options too.

As a data point for comparison, I was able to fetch from the Internet (which is much slower than from a storage) and process millions of documents per hour (extract, clean, index, etc.) on a regular App Engine instance.